# Speed up Nested Loop query on two simple postgres tables (with macaddr datatype)

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, query-optimization

I have two simple tables `node` and `node_ip` linked using a foreign key like this:

```
CREATE TABLE node_ip (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    node_id int4 NOT NULL,
    ip inet NULL
);

CREATE TABLE node (
  id serial NOT NULL,
  mac macaddr NULL,
  is_local bool,
  CONSTRAINT node_pkey PRIMARY KEY ( id)

);

ALTER TABLE node_ip ADD CONSTRAINT node_const
   FOREIGN KEY (node_id) REFERENCES node(id);
```

and the following indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_node_ip_1 ON node_ip USING btree (ip)
CREATE INDEX idx_node_1    ON node    USING btree (id) WHERE ((NOT is_local) AND ((mac)::text !~~ '02:00:00%'::text))
```

I am trying to optimize the following query:

```
select * from node_ip
where ip = '192.168.1.6'
  and node_id in (select id from node
                  where is_local = false
                  and mac::text not like '02:00:00%');
```

However this is the best i can get:

```
Gather  (cost=1352.74..29923.00 rows=13921 width=46) (actual time=1.905..32.612 rows=14656 loops=1)
  Workers Planned: 2
  Workers Launched: 2
  ->  Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=352.74..27530.90 rows=5800 width=46) (actual time=0.694..20.534 rows=4885 loops=3)
        ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on node_ip  (cost=352.32..22986.04 rows=5800 width=46) (actual time=0.638..3.547 rows=4892 loops=3)
              Recheck Cond: (ip = '192.168.1.6'::inet)
              Heap Blocks: exact=491
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_node_ip_1  (cost=0.00..348.84 rows=13921 width=0) (actual time=1.381..1.381 rows=14676 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (ip = '192.168.1.6'::inet)
        ->  Index Only Scan using idx_node_1 on node  (cost=0.42..0.77 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=14676)
              Index Cond: (id = node_ip.node_id)
              Heap Fetches: 4328
Planning Time: 0.616 ms
Execution Time: 33.310 ms
```

Info about the tables:

```
select count(*) from node ;   --  500000
select count(*) from node_ip; -- 2500000
select count(*) from node where is_local = false and mac::text not like '02:00:00%'; -- 300000
```

From the plan it looks like most of the time is spent on the `Nested Loop Semi Join`, is there any way to speed this up?

Related question: What is the best index available for `macaddr` type? Where most of my queries are `LIKE '02:00:00%'`?

Note: Am using `postgres 11`

Comment: I dont know enough about Postgres to be sure, but I would test the query using `select distinct node_ip.* from node join node_ip on node_ip.id=node.id where <your clause>`

Comment: 33 milliseconds doesn't look too bad. How fast do you need that to be? Did you try an `EXISTS` condition instead of `IN`?

Comment: What plan and timing do you get if you first `set enable_nestloop TO off` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should

```
VACUUM node;
```

to get rid of the 4328 heap fetches caused by a visibility map that is not up to date. If that helps as it should, consider tuning `autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor` for this table so that it gets vacuumed more often.